# Data Recovery - Recovering data from broken harddrive

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, mybook

I have a several year old (want to say around 7 years old) external hard drive (WD My Book - 1 TB)that stopped working a while back. When I would plug it in to my PC, it would show up as a plugged in drive, but I wouldn't be able to read any of the information on it.

I brought it to my friendly neighborhood IT professional, and upon opening the case up, he pointed out that there must have been a power surge at some point and the controller board shorted (tried to show that in the second picture, although it looks like the first picture may actually be much clearer).

Does anyone have any advice on how to recover the information from the drive? I wouldn't be against trying to replace the pieces if need be, but not entirely sure what exactly I'd need to replace (I have also included a picture of the drive type, in case that helps).

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: Drive's controller board.]

[image: Specific area that was fried.]

[image: Drive information.]

Comment: You would have to replace the controller board with **exactly the same model** to have any hope of recovering the data. It might be a better idea to use a data recovery service.

Comment: I agree that board is mega hosed.  What service likely will do is likely transfer the platters to the new drive.

Answer (score 2):

You would certainly need a new PCB to replace this broken one.

There are several services that sell you exact PCB matches to what you have.

Something like this once would probably be good http://www.hddzone.com/wd10eads-wd-pcb-2060771640003-rev-a-p1-p2-p-1386.html